# GPS device is not listening to UDP requests

Tags: c#, udp

I have created an application where i am getting data from GPS device via GPRS and also sending the data. I can successfully get the data from the device. I have to send some UDP packets to configure the device if needed.
Manufacturer has given me a device simulator. When testing with device simulator, both running on different VM servers, i can successfully send and receive UDP packets. But with real device i can only get the data from device, but device is not responding/accepting the UDP data from our application.
What could be the reason?? Please Help.

Comment: Tried looking at the traffic with a tool like `tcpdump`?

Comment: Usually it is because you are not terminating the command with a return or using the wrong type of return.

Comment: @jdweng it is working correctly with simulator on other server. i tried sending the UDP packet and then terminating the command but still not any response from device.

Comment: Is it possible that you have two devices set to the same IP address which is causing a conflict.  Turn off the device that you cannot communicate with.  The from cmd.exe try ping the device by name or IP.  If you get a response then you have an IP conflict.  Seen this problem a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. Actually i have to use the same socket for sending and receiving the device data, once applied it is working correctly.